# Automate Google Meet using python

Tags: python, google-meet

I want my code to join a google meet as I say which I have done using webbrowser module. But I also want that my assistant to join the class with mic and cam off. Can some1 pls suggest me a way with which I can make my assistant join the class with mic off and cam off.

Comment: You could use Selenium for that

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

I used the "google meet enhancement suite" plugin from the webstore for that part, works great for me. If you are using chrome then that should work just fine.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-meet-enhancement-s/ljojmlmdapmnibgflmmminacbjebjpno

Comment: so can i integrate it with python. If so then how ?

Answer (score -1):

I can answer only now, sorry. Try:

```
import: webbrwoser

code = input("enter the code: ")

webbrowser.open("https://meet.google.com/{}".format(code))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help but i knew this, what I wanted to ask was how do i control my mics and camera settings using python without doing it manually. Like to turn them on / off from python

Answer (score -1):

Google Meet accepts keypresses in order to turn your camera/microphone off, such as ctrl d for your microphone and ctrl e for your camera. You could use the [Pynput module, which allows you to control output devices and simulate the keypresses.](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)